# How would you unionize N-arrays with different sizes?

Tags: python, numpy, union

The :

```
 np.union1d(a, b)
```

can unionize two arrays with different sizes.

```
 np.vstack((a, b, c)).T.ravel()
```

can unionize N arrays of the same size.

How would you unionize N-arrays with different sizes ?
And of course it should be fast ;) !

---

btw union is not just concatenation...
still testing, but would this do it :

```
 np.unique(np.concatenate((a,b,c)))
```

Comment: Are all elements in all input arrays integers? If so, are they also just positive numbers?

Comment: yes positive integers

Answer (score 1):

Here's one with `array-assignment` + `masking` for positive numbers -

```
def unionize_ndarrays(L, maxnum=None):
    if maxnum is None:
        maxnum = max([np.max(i) for i in L])+1
        # for lists : max([max(i) for i in L])+1
    id_ar = np.zeros(maxnum, dtype=bool)
    for i in L:
        id_ar[i] = True
    return np.flatnonzero(id_ar)
```

Computing the max number `maxnum` has noticeable runtime and could be the bottleneck even for a large number of small arrays. So, if that's known, feeding that in should help a lot on those scenarios.

Sample run -

```
In [43]: a = np.array([0, 1, 3, 4, 3])
    ...: b = np.array([0, 10, 3, 1, 2, 1])
    ...: c = np.array([6, 3, 4, 2])

In [44]: np.unique(np.concatenate((a,b,c)))
Out[44]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  6, 10])

In [45]: unionize_ndarrays((a,b,c))
Out[45]: array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  6, 10])
```

**Benchmarking**

1) Small sized arrays -

```
In [106]: L = [np.random.randint(0,10,n) for n in np.random.randint(4,10,10000)]

In [107]: %timeit unionize_ndarrays(L, maxnum=10)
2.74 ms ± 207 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [108]: %timeit np.unique(np.concatenate((L)))
3.06 ms ± 24.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

# Without maxnum fed
In [109]: %timeit unionize_ndarrays(L)
40.4 ms ± 542 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

If order is not important, we can also look into `pandas.factorize`, if we are dealing with small-sized arrays -

```
In [76]: a = np.array([0, 1, 3, 4, 3])
    ...: b = np.array([0, 10, 3, 1, 2, 1])
    ...: c = np.array([6, 3, 4, 2])

In [77]: L = [a,b,c]

In [80]: import pandas as pd

In [81]: pd.factorize(np.concatenate(L))[1]
Out[81]: array([ 0,  1,  3,  4, 10,  2,  6])
```

Related timings -

```
In [82]: L = [np.random.randint(0,10,n) for n in np.random.randint(4,10,10000)]

In [84]: %timeit pd.factorize(np.concatenate(L))[1]
2.1 ms ± 13.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

2) Big-sized (bigger variation in sizes) arrays -

Timings -

```
In [2]: L = [np.random.randint(0,1000,n) for n in np.random.randint(10,1000,10000)]

In [3]: %timeit unionize_ndarrays(L, maxnum=1000)
   ...: %timeit unionize_ndarrays(L)
   ...: %timeit np.unique(np.concatenate((L)))
14 ms ± 925 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
56.6 ms ± 641 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
242 ms ± 773 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So, to choose one will depend on whether we have the priori info on max number and the size variation.

Comment: thanks for detailed comparison... seems like concatenate is a good choice

Answer (score 0):

From [NumPy manual](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.union1d.html):

> To find the union of more than two arrays, use functools.reduce:

```py
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> reduce(np.union1d, ([1, 3, 4, 3], [3, 1, 2, 1], [6, 3, 4, 2]))
```

```
array([1, 2, 3, 4, 6])
```

This also works with arrays of different sizes:

```py
>>> reduce(np.union1d, ([0, 1, 3, 4, 3], [0, 10, 3, 1, 2, 1], [6, 3, 4, 2]))
```

```
array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  6, 10])
```

Comment: wouldn't this be slow ... it uses python rather numpy